# Getting Current User in .NET Core Console

Tags: .net, .net-core

In a .NET Core console application (note: not ASP.NET Core!), how can I get the current user? To be clear, I'm looking for what used to be available as Thread.CurrentPrincipal, which no longer exists.
PlatformServices does not contain this information, and neither does Environment.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Got it. A possible option is to use WindowsIdentity:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

It is necessary to add the System.Security.Principal.Windows package.
Of course, this is for Windows only.

Another option is to use Claims:

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current
```

For that, the package to add is System.Security.Claims. In Windows, by default, the identity will be empty.

Comment: What I hear between the lines: ClaimsPrincipal is the future ;)

Comment: `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` will *not* work in a controller, it will be null. You need to access the `HttpContext.User` property, which will indeed be a `ClaimsPrincipal` instance.

Comment: Good to know. A static API for ClaimsPrinciple does not make so much sense anyway IMHO.

Comment: Good news.  Environment has been re-added to .NET Core.  https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Environment.UserName

Comment: in a console application `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` is null

Answer (score 16):

`System.Security.Principal.Windows` is not available unless you import the DLL manually. The following worked for me:

```
Environment.UserName;
```

<s>According to the [.NET Core System.Environment Source Code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/src/System/Environment.Unix.cs#L367), this solution "should suffice in 99% of cases."</s>

Note: Be sure you are targeting `DotNetCore 2.0` or later as `1.0` and `1.1` do not have this definition.

Edit Jan 22 2019: The link to the old source of the method has gone stale. [PR 34654](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/34654) moved `System.Environment` to live in `CoreLib`. For those curious to [read the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Environment.Unix.cs#L365), you may still do so, though the comment suggesting it "should suffice in 99% of cases" has been removed.

Comment: I don't seem to have a `.UserName` in `Environment`

Comment: Make sure you're targeting `DotNetCore 2.0` or later. `DotNetCore 1.0` and `DotNetCore 1.1` do not appear to have `.UserName`.

Comment: Cool works for me. @Foxtrek_64 anyway to set the user? As I am deploying it on Linux server and want to set user to service account

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse `IIdentity` abstraction to pass through your middle layer do this:

```
var identity = new GenericIdentity(Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName, "Anonymous");
```

P.S. in core 2 console app: 
`ClaimsPrincipal.Current` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` are always null (unless you have setup them) and this code will not work either:

```
IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(principal);
```

after this `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` are still null.

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` works, but there should be more strong reasons to reference `System.Security.Principal.Window` then get the "user name".

Comment: Future readers.  For the GenericIdentity idea....watch out for the auto-magic-voodoo'ed IsAuthenticated gets set to True !  Thanks RP for the idea.  Here is the code to see the voodoo.   https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/principal/genericidentity.cs  (find "public override bool IsAuthenticated")